# java string comparison fails?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm really puzzled about why this `if` statement keeps failing. I'm comparing a value and it always returns false.

String userDetail = "john";

```
 if (sentence.equals(userDetail))
 {

 String returnval = "100%";
 sendData = returnval.getBytes();
 DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
 serverConn.send(sendPacket); 
 }
 else
 {
 String returnval = sentence;
 sendData = returnval.getBytes();
 DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
 serverConn.send(sendPacket); 
 }
```

I am positive that "sentence" does equal john. AS you can see I have been doing troubleshooting so in the `else` statement, I set the return value to sentence and it does return john.

ANy suggestions?

Comment: `I am positive that "sentence" does equal john.` A decade of Java development disagrees with you. But seriously, maybe it contains characters that appear as whitespace, so you cannot debug it by printing it. Check the `String`'s bytes or check its length.

Comment: Have you tried printing the sentence value, if so what was the result?

Comment: I see no return statements in here, so what does 'it returns' mean?

Comment: Yeap tried printing sentence value and it was what I expected. return statements first line.

Comment: Just to double check, try `sentence.trim().equals(userDetail)`

Comment: When you're learning to program, you should assume that all bugs are your fault. The chances of a newbie finding a bug are pretty slim.

Comment: no luck with that broslow

Comment: Add `System.out.println("'" + sentence + "'");` And then post the value of `sentence`.

Comment: 'john'
is what is displayed on screen.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable does appear to equal "john", it is possible that it contains some extra whitespace.

To remove the whitespace in the beginning and end of the string, use:

```
sentence.trim()
```